# Setting .className of SVG path not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a chevron SVG at the bottom of my page that I want to hide once the user scrolls down. I can't figure out why my JS isn't working and the chevron is never hidden:

NOTE: the console.log statements do run and the css stylesheet does work.

```js
chevron = document.getElementById("down-accelerate-path");

window.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
  const y = window.scrollY;
  if (y >= 1) {
    console.log(y + " " + chevron)
    chevron.className = ""
    chevron.hidden = true;
  } else {
    chevron.className = "hide"
    chevron.hidden = false;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

#down-accelerate {
  position: fixed;
  top: 88%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<span class="center">
        <svg height=88 width=88 viewBox="0 0 444.819 444.819" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id = "down-accelerate">
            <path id="down-accelerate-path" style="" fill="white" stroke="none"
                  d="M434.252,114.203l-21.409-21.416c-7.419-7.04-16.084-10.561-25.975-10.561c-10.095,0-18.657,3.521-25.7,10.561
        L222.41,231.549L83.653,92.791c-7.042-7.04-15.606-10.561-25.697-10.561c-9.896,0-18.559,3.521-25.979,10.561l-21.128,21.416
        C3.615,121.436,0,130.099,0,140.188c0,10.277,3.619,18.842,10.848,25.693l185.864,185.865c6.855,7.23,15.416,10.848,25.697,10.848
        c10.088,0,18.75-3.617,25.977-10.848l185.865-185.865c7.043-7.044,10.567-15.608,10.567-25.693
        C444.819,130.287,441.295,121.629,434.252,114.203z"/>
    </svg>
</span>
```

Comment: I can't even see it when it's not supposed to be hidden?! Just a random idea, though. Try to show hide parent span. Not sure if there is maybe some weirdness with the fact that's you try to do that on an SVG path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to be working. But I couldn't see the chevron. So I made it black and changed its position for testing. I also cleaned up the code a bit.

```js
chevron = document.getElementById("chevron");

window.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
  const y = window.scrollY;
  if (y >= 1) {
    chevron.className = 'hide'
  } else {
    chevron.className = ''
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

#down-accelerate {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span class="center" id="chevron">
        <svg height=88 width=88 viewBox="0 0 444.819 444.819" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id = "down-accelerate">
            <path id="down-accelerate-path" style="" fill="black" stroke="none"
                  d="M434.252,114.203l-21.409-21.416c-7.419-7.04-16.084-10.561-25.975-10.561c-10.095,0-18.657,3.521-25.7,10.561
        L222.41,231.549L83.653,92.791c-7.042-7.04-15.606-10.561-25.697-10.561c-9.896,0-18.559,3.521-25.979,10.561l-21.128,21.416
        C3.615,121.436,0,130.099,0,140.188c0,10.277,3.619,18.842,10.848,25.693l185.864,185.865c6.855,7.23,15.416,10.848,25.697,10.848
        c10.088,0,18.75-3.617,25.977-10.848l185.865-185.865c7.043-7.044,10.567-15.608,10.567-25.693
        C444.819,130.287,441.295,121.629,434.252,114.203z"/>
    </svg>
</span>
```